# PHP application with remote MSSQL DB slower than on local

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

We are moving from one server architecture to two servers, web and DB.

The two new servers are VMs on one physical box. The VMs have a private virtual network setup so they can talk to each other directly with local IP without going through any other switches in the data center but their virtual switch. Pinging one VM from the other is less < 1ms.

We have two applications running on these servers, one is built in c#.NET and the other one is in PHP.

.NET application has no issues with the two VMs setup.

PHP, however, has a latency of about 400ms more compared to the application running on a server with application and db residing on that server.

To make sure the queries in the db are not a problem, we installed the application on the db VM to run it locally, and it was running at the same speed as on our previous server. So queries are not a problem.

Any ideas what could be causing the issue???

Comment: DNS lookup? Are you identifying the remote server by name or by IP address?

Comment: seconded. yeah, its probably DNS lookup failing with the setup of the private network

Comment: I'm identifying it by a local IP address, so it's not a DNS lookup.

Comment: If it was DNS lookup, .NET applications would have the same issue, but the .NET application is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the network to see what's happening?

Comment: can you benchmark it though? see exactly which line(s) use considerably more time than it should use?